# Unable to generate jmeter html report from java code

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

When trying to generate html report using java code, I can only see a statistics.json generated but no html reports are there.

My Java Code -

```
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(csvFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

//run
StandardJMeterEngine jMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
jMeterEngine.configure(testPlanTree);
jMeterEngine.run();

//Report Generator
ReportGenerator rg = new ReportGenerator(csvFile, null);
rg.generate();
```

In my reportgenerator.properties, I have following entries (only end part)

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.template_dir=report-template
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.property.output_dir=report-output
```

I have checked that the csv file is generated and has valid data, because i tried generating html report from jmeter command line using the same csv and it worked. 
After the execution, my java code only produces a statistics.json file but no html reports are generated. There are no errors in the logs (only few warnings related to some properties not set and default being used). 
**Edit** 
I'm setting the JMeter property `jmeter.reportgenerator.outputdir` in java code -

```
properties.put(org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "report-path");
```

The output logs -

```
   Creating statistics for overall
    Creating statistics for other transactions
    Checking output folder
    Writing statistics JSON to path\to\dir\statistics.json
    Exporting data using exporter:'html' of 
 className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter'
    Will generate dashboard in folder: path\to\dir
```

It says 'will generate dashboard in folder' in the logs but no html is generated. 
Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: thanks for sharing, I was able to generate with the help of your example

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a very obvious thing: the **location** of the generated [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

You need to set `jmeter.reportgenerator.outputdir` [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) and provide the full path of the dashboard as the value, to wit before initialization of the [ReportGenerator](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/ReportGenerator.html) add the next line:

```
JMeterUtils.setProperty(org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "/full/path/to/the/dashboard/folder");
```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I missed this in original question but I am setting this property. still no html , only json file is generated. The difficult part is there are no errors in the log even after putting 'generate' call in try-catch

Answer (score 1):

After checking out all the configurations, I went on to debug the code in JMeter's ReportGenerator class, to check at what point the code fails. Here' the hierarchy of the code used in gnerating html reports -

```
ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(csvFileName, null);
generator.generate();
```

---

```
 public void generate() throws GenerationException {
 -----
 exportData(sampleContext, key, value);
 -----
 }
```

---

```
private void exportData(SampleContext sampleContext, String exporterName,
        ExporterConfiguration exporterConfiguration)
        throws GenerationException {
----
 exporter.export(sampleContext, testFile, configuration);
----
}
```

---

Eventualy, export() method of HTMLTemplateExporter is invoked - 
`public void export(SampleContext context, File file,
            ReportGeneratorConfiguration configuration) throws ExportException {
    ----
    Configuration templateCfg = new Configuration(
                Configuration.getVersion());
    ----`

The code fails here while creating new configuration for Freemarker. JMeter internally uses Freemarker templating engine to generate the dashboard reports.

On further analysis, I could figure out that I had conflicting dependencies for Freemarker library. Freemarker dependencies are added with JMeter lib itslef, while my application was already using a different vesion of freemarker library. I had to exclude one of the versions (using exclude tags in pom.xml) and made sure that only one version is present. (You can check this using maven dependency tree.)

PS - Although in maven dependency tree, initialy it appeared that the older version was omitted and only one version is being used. It was the reason I didn't doubt on the library versions conflict. But on debugging, I was convinced that the code was failing due to conflicting libs, and I had to explicitly make sure that only one lib version is there.